# Return correct value from recursive indexOf

Tags: javascript, recursion, return, indexof

I've written a recursive function to mimic .indexOf in JavaScript.

When stepping through the debugger, everything works as expected except when the `item` argument is not present in the array. The stop condition is triggered when `arr.length === 0` but then the callstack unwinds and returns the total length of the array.

If the `item` isn't present, it should return `-1`.

I'm new to recursion and think that I might be missing a piece of logic. Any help is appreciated.

```
function search(arr, item) {
    if (arr[0] === item) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    let remainingArr = arr.slice(1);

    if (arr[0] !== item && arr.length !== 0) {
         return 1 + search(remainingArr, item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematical induction can guide your program. Numbered steps correspond to the numbered lines in the program comments -

1. if position, `pos`, is out of bounds of the array, `a`, return `-1`
2. (inductive) the position is in bounds. if `a[pos]` matches the query, `q`, return `pos`
3. (inductive) the position is in bounds and `a[pos]` does not match the query. return the recursive result.

NB the *order* of steps is important. For example, we don't want to attempt to read `a[pos]` (step 2) before we check if `pos` is out of bounds (step 1)!

```js
const search = (a, q, pos = 0) =>
  pos >= a.length
    ? -1                // 1
: a[pos] === q
    ? pos               // 2
: search(a, q, pos + 1) // 3

console.log(search(["a", "b", "c", "d"], "c")) // 2
console.log(search(["a", "b", "c", "d"], "z")) // -1
```

You can make `search` a higher-order function, if you wanted -

```js
const search = (a, f, pos = 0) =>
  pos >= a.length
    ? -1
: Boolean(f(a[pos]))
    ? pos
: search(a, f, pos + 1)

console.log(search(["a", "b", "c", "d"], v => v === "c")) // 2
console.log(search(["a", "b", "c", "d"], v => v > "a"))   // 1
console.log(search(["a", "b", "c", "d"], v => v > "z"))   // -1
```

---

Did you notice how the third parameter, `pos`, gets assigned a *default value* of 0 when we call `search` with only *two* arguments?

```js
search([ 4, 99, 5, 8, 1, 9, 5, 11 ], 5) // pos = 0
// => 2
```

And maybe it's useful to say, starting at `pos=3`, find the first position of `5` -

```js
search([ 4, 99, 5, 8, 1, 9, 5, 11 ], 5, 3) // third argument; pos = 3
// => 5
```

But maybe you don't want that third parameter in the function. In this modification, `loop` has the same logic as our first function. `search` is a simple wrapper around `loop` -

```js
function search(a, q)
{ function loop(pos)
  { return pos >= a.length
      ? -1
    : a[pos] === q
      ? pos
    : loop(pos + 1)
  }
  return loop(0)
}

console.log(search(["a", "b", "c", "d"], "c")) // 2
console.log(search(["a", "b", "c", "d"], "z")) // -1
```

With this change, `search` only responds to two arguments -

```js
search([ 4, 99, 5, 8, 1, 9, 5, 11 ], 5, 3) // third argument ignored
// => 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Only add 1 to the recursive call if the result is a whole number (0 or more); if the result is -1, return just -1:

```
function search(arr, item) {
    if (arr[0] === item) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    const result = search(arr.slice(1), item);
    return result === -1 ? -1 : result + 1;
}
```

```js
function search(arr, item) {
    if (arr[0] === item) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    const result = search(arr.slice(1), item);
    return result === -1 ? -1 : result + 1;
}

console.log(
  search([1, 2, 3, 4], 3),
  search([1, 2, 3, 4], -333),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd pass the count through to the recursive call.

Also, your escape clause should come first. Doesn't matter so much in JS but `arr[0] === item` is meaningless when there's nothing in the array.

```js
function search(arr, item, count = 0) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  
  if (arr[0] === item) {
    return count;
  }

  return search(arr.slice(1), item, count + 1);
}

console.log(
  search([1, 2, 3, 4], 3),
  search([1, 2, 3, 4], -333),
);
```

---

In fact, this way you could do it without the `.slice(1)`, since the `count` can serve as an index.

```js
function search(arr, item, count = 0) {
  if (arr.length === count) {
    return -1;
  }
  
  if (arr[count] === item) {
    return count;
  }

  return search(arr, item, count + 1);
}

console.log(
  search([1, 2, 3, 4], 3),
  search([1, 2, 3, 4], -333),
);
```